# How to post an array of data using ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax

i have a form that posts data using ajax to a php script

when i pass one value it works as i expect, but now i need to pass multiple values and i have added an array attr to my texfield.

```
<input type="hidden" name="fav[]" id="fav" value="<?php echo 
$row_trx['jobid']; ?>">
```

i then try to view the data this way.

**ajax**

```
 var fav=document.getElementById( "fav" );

  if(fav)
    {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'loq.php',
  data: {
 fav:fav.value,
 },
  error: function (request, error) {
  // error
  },
  success: function (response) {

  $( '#pep<?php echo $row_trx['jobid']; ?>' ).html(response);
  //alert('success');
  }
```

**php**

```
 if( isset( $_POST['fav'] ) )
 {

 $fav = $_POST['fav'];


  foreach( $fav as $key => $n ) {
  echo $n;
  }
```

**i get a invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP _POST['fav'] has a string value so on the PHP (i.e. server) side you'd need to parse that to a PHP array via json_decode.
Furthermore in your ajax request you'd need to send an array.

Comment: can u please help re adjust my code to show wat ure saying in both the ajax and php code i av provided thanks

Comment: never mind, ur explaination helped me sort it out thanks